# Movie or tv scene with many species of aliens

Tags: movie, tv, story-identification

Decades ago I watched a TV documentary in the USA about science fiction or horror movies or some related subject.  I don't remember its title.

As I remember a very interesting scene was shown beneath some of the closing credits.

It was a sort of an "assembly of aliens" scene in which aliens of various species are gathered together for some reason. There have been many other such scenes and this one might be the first one.  In any case I would like to know where it is from.

The scene I am trying to identify was shown in black and white in the closing credits of the Scifi documentary whose title I forget and was outdoors on an alien planet with a black, star-studded sky beyond the painted horizon, and a long table.  Behind the table a group of aliens of various species sat or stood or whatever.

One or more of the aliens had a highly abstract style like they might be more plant or machine than animal.  I do not remember any scenes in the documentary itself that looked like they came from the same movie or episode as this scene.

The comment by Simon Bucher-Jones suggests it might possibly be a scene of the Daleks' allies from *Doctor Who* "The Daleks' Master Plan".  If so, that scifi documentary with the forgotten title might preserve an otherwise lost clip from the episode.

Someone who owns copies of many TV programs about science fiction in movies and TV could look at the closing credits of them to look for this scene, and if they find it  post it.  An image of that scene would certainly help to identify where it comes from.

So can anyone identify this scene with many aliens?

Comment: Possibly the delegates to the Daleks' meetings in THE DALEKS' MASTER-PLAN?  Image shown on wikipedia here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_to_the_Unknown

Comment: Simon Bucher-Jones - I have long suspected that the Dalek's allies in "The Daleks' Master Plan" could be what I am looking for.  And the alien Sentreal http://misc.thefullwiki.org/Sentreal does have the abstract look I remember at least one of the aliens having.  But I remember the scene being outdoors and not in a council chamber.  If your suggestion is correct that would mean the program in question would contain a missing scene from "The Daleks' Master Plan".

Comment: There's another photo with high backed chairs around a curved conference table. The walls of the chamber are black and might suggest the sky?  http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Council

Comment: This review of Evil brain From Outer Space (1965) says that movie is featured in It Came from Hollywood.   http://www.stomptokyo.com/badmoviereport/reviews/E/evilbrain.html               
                                                                                                               And the Wikipedia article on It Came From Hollywood (1982) lists Evil Brain from Outer Space (1964) as one of the B movies discussed and made fun of in it.      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Came_from_Hollywood

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like I didn't need to ask this question.  I seem to have found the answer by myself.

I had a hunch that the scene could be from a Japanese movie or TV series, and tried looking up Japanese horror, scifi, and superheo movies.

The Japanese short movie series *Supa Jaiantsu* had 9 films produced from 1957 to 1959 featuring Super Giant, a hero from outer space called Starman in English versions.  They were edited into four movies and dubbed into English with the titles *Atomic Rulers of the World* (1964), *Invaders from Space* (1965), *Attack from Space* (1964), and *Evil Brain from Outer Space* (1964).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Giant

I found online reviews of *Attack from Space* (1964) and *Atomic Rulers of the World* (1964) that include stills of a scene very similar to what I remember.

http://tarstarkas.net/2004/07/starman-attack-from-space/

https://commonsensemoviereviews.blogspot.com/2009/05/atomic-rulers-of-world-1964.html

So it seems that the scene I remember was from the Starman series of films.

Added 09-24/25-2020.   And I guess I should add that the TV program or movie with clips from many films that the scene was in seems to have been *It Came From Hollywood* (1982).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Came_from_Hollywood

Comment: Did you intend linked words within the text, or URLs displayed on their own lines? Either way the markup doesn't seem to be working properly.

Comment: @deltab  I redid the links early in the morning of 01-15-2022 and the links are working as of that moment.